# Virtual host with sails.js

Tags: sails.js

I want to have subdomains for my app.
For example:

```
myapp.com  
admin.myapp.com  
static.myapp.com
```

And directory structure like this:

```
myapp
  frontend [sails app] -> myapp.com
  backend [sails app] -> admin.myapp.com
  static [express app] -> static.myapp.com
  app.js
```

In express I could use vhost.
How can I achieve this in sails.js?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it, but I think it can be done using Nginx's reverse proxy.

Let's say you have 2 SailsJS projects (Sails1 and Sails2) configured to run on two different ports (port 1337 and port 1338) respectively. You can configure the SailsJS app to run on any port by making changes in /config/locals.js

Now follow below steps:

- Run both applications using "sails lift" or "forever" commands
- Install Nginx
- Config Nginx

> $ cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/
>
> $ sudo touch sails1.conf
>
> $ sudo touch sails2.conf
>
> $sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/sails1.conf
>   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sails1.com.conf
>
> $ sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/sails2.conf
>   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sails2.conf

Put below content in /etc/nginx/sites-available/sails1.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sails1.com;
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Put below content in /etc/nginx/sites-available/sails2.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sails2.com;
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:1338;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Restart Nginx and try accessing sails.com and sails2.com hopefully you should be able to see both your website.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used vhosts directly with sails, but you can access the underlying express engine pretty easily..

```
//./config/express.js
module.exports.express = {
    customMiddleware: function (app) {

        app.use(vhost('*.example.com', require('app1'));  
            app.use(vhost('example.com', function(..){...})); 


            app.use('/queue', require('kue').app);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to mount sails app to vhost? Something like this: `app.use(vhost('sub.example.com', require('subsails')));`

Comment: hmm, well I think you might be able to do what you want by creating an empty express app. and then using `require('sails').express.app` instead of `require('subsails')`. Keep in mind that I've never done that before.. I've only used other express engines inside of sails. I don't see why it wouldnt work though.

Comment: I tried that but it failed. `require('sails').express.app` is undefined. Because `lift` hasn't been called I think. What I want is to have `example.com` and `admin.example.com`. They need to maintain their own sails directory structure. It's like having 2 sails app and a master app to execute these sails app

Comment: Ahh. Try require('sails').lift().express.app

Comment: `require('sails').lift()` doesn't return anything. It throw this error: `Cannot read property 'express' of undefined`